# Divergence Theorem Clarification

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals, greens-theorem, divergence-theorem

This is the first time I'm doing this kind of problem, and I'm (understandably I think :)) hesitant about my answer. The question is:

> Compute $\iint_{\partial Q}\ F\bullet ndS$ using the easiest method available where $Q$ is bounded by $z=4-x^2-y^2, z=1$ and $z=0$. $F=<z^3,x^2y,y^2z>$.

This is the work I did:
    Divergence of F: $0+x^2+y^2\\
 \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{1}r^3dz\ dr\ d\theta\\
 =\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2}r^3dr\ d\theta\\
 =\int_{0}^{2\pi}4d\theta\\
 =8\pi$

Is this right? Like I said it's the first time I'm doing it and so I'm looking for feedback - on my bounds, my set up etc.

Comment: Your bounds are not correct. Ignore theta and draw the curves in an $rz$ plane.

Answer (score 1):

If you do $z$ first this will need to be two integrals. Doing $r$ first makes it one:

$$I = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 \int_0^{\sqrt{4-z}} r^3\:dr\:dz\:d\theta =\frac{37\pi}{6}$$

Comment: I see - that is because $r^2=4-z$. So, instead of putting in a number, you just put in that. But, we know that $z$ goes from zero to one. r will be largest when z=0 - at which point it will be two. So, why can't I put in two as my upper bound for r?

Comment: And, why would I need two integrals?

Comment: @Burt you have to draw the picture.

Comment: I did - can't attach it here. I still don't understand why I would need two integrals.

Comment: I suppose you can't set the bounds of r static because that way doesn't define the integral well enough.